# Space out various service checks for a host with Nagios

Tags: nagios

Anyone know if there is way to time various service checks per host?

So for example, if I have hostA and 5 different services checks for that host.  Each of those checks happens every 5 minutes.  Can I make so I have a check every minute or so, instead of 5 checks pretty much at once?

Comment: Sadly nagios's scheduler really isn't that clever. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** On further reading it seems like you may have been looking for a **per host** option. If this is the case than, unfortunately, the `service_inter_check_delay_method` is more of a global setting and doesnt have the host level granularity that you may be looking for, I'll keep this post around in case others find it useful for their installs.

Sadly the official documentation hasnt been ported over from Nagios 2, but you may try playing with the `service_inter_check_delay_method` option in your Nagios config.

Old Docs: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/2_0/checkscheduling.html

```
# SERVICE INTER-CHECK DELAY METHOD
# This is the method that Nagios should use when initially
# "spreading out" service checks when it starts monitoring.  The
# default is to use smart delay calculation, which will try to
# space all service checks out evenly to minimize CPU load.
# Using the dumb setting will cause all checks to be scheduled
# at the same time (with no delay between them)!  This is not a
# good thing for production, but is useful when testing the
# parallelization functionality.
#       n       = None - don't use any delay between checks
#       d       = Use a "dumb" delay of 1 second between checks
#       s       = Use "smart" inter-check delay calculation
#       x.xx    = Use an inter-check delay of x.xx seconds

service_inter_check_delay_method=s
```

So instead of the default 'smart' method try something like `service_inter_check_delay_method=60`

Note: the default smart check method works very well, if you choose to use a static x delay check, be sure to do a LOT of testing to make sure this doesnt flood your network in unusual and interesting ways... ;-)

Comment: Another thing you might want to check into is modifying check_multi to sleep 60 in between its checks. This _would_ scale at the host level, but you will need to dive into the check_multi code a little. http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Others/check_multi/details